# php array with nested arrays as query parameter implode/explode

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, get

i have to send this array with nested arrays

```
            $tags=[];
            foreach ($importedTags->tags as $key => $value) {
                $tags[]=array(
                    "name"=>$value->getName(),
                    "id"=>$value->getId(),
                );
            }
```

the array (if there were 3 importedTags) may look like this :

```
array(3) { 
   [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(14) "foo" ["id"]=> string(7) "3375095" } 
   [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(12) "bar" ["id"]=> string(7) "3378925" } 
   [2]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(8) "foobar" ["id"]=> string(7) "3405555" } 
}
```

as a GET query parameter on a url

i tryed

```
            $params=array(
                "pageId"=>$pageId,
                "tags"=>urlencode(implode(",", $tags))
            );

return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('my_route.create_sth',$params));
```

but when i parse it like

```
    $tags=urldecode($request->query->get('tags'));
            $tags=explode(",",$tags);
```

it returns to

```
array(3) {  
     [0]=> string(5) "Array" 
     [1]=> string(5) "Array" 
     [2]=> string(5) "Array" 
}
```

and i know why its like this, and this makes sense

but i´m a php newbie, so how can i solve this and get a string representation like i tryed to get with implode and explode to get array back with such nested arrays?

Comment: They aren't nested arrays. They're strings (as you can see from `var_dump`) with the *string* content `Array`. You're most likely trying to cast an array to a string at some point.

Comment: Note `$tags` is a bi-dimensional array. You have `$tags[$item]["name"]` and `$tags[$item]["id"]`, so a mere `implode` does not convert it into flat string. What value do you want to send on GET, name or id?

Comment: @h2ooooooo hmn sry for bad wording, updated first line of text @ fedorqui i need the whole array with its nested arrays

Comment: (Note you cannot use @ for two people in the same comment, just first one gets notified) How do you want the string to look like?

Comment: when i parse the queryparameter i want to have the full array with its access, so im looking for a way to string-representate the array with nested array, i updated the answer with var_dump($tags) before they get send

Comment: Hi, according to \Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator::doGenerate() - base generator class of symfony, there is no way to pass parameters array other than flat. If you must pass nested params try to generate params like ?param1=3375095|foo&param2=3378925|bar etc. On the other site just split them by '|' char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change generating of params to:

```
$params=[];
foreach ($importedTags->tags as $key => $value)
{
    $params[]=$value->getName() .'|'. $value->getId();
}

$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('my_route.create_sth',$params));
```

on the other site do:

```
$tags=[];
foreach ($params as $param)
{
    $paramArray = split('|', $param);
    $tags[$paramArray[0]]=$paramArray[1];
}
```

and you have nested array.

good luck